# Editing Windows Folder

Tags: windows-8

I want to remove the yellow highlighted folders from the "This computer" list. 
Is this some how possible?

I've no clue on what I should google. I can't find any editing options. I hope SU can help.

Greetings Jochem

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use Powershell you can use the tool [This PC Tweaker](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.213) to edit and remove the entries.

Answer (score 5):

Run this snippet in Powershell console to delete them.

```
Remove-Item -Path 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}'
Remove-Item -Path 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{A8CDFF1C-4878-43be-B5FD-F8091C1C60D0}'
Remove-Item -Path 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}'
Remove-Item -Path 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{1CF1260C-4DD0-4ebb-811F-33C572699FDE}'
Remove-Item -Path 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{3ADD1653-EB32-4cb0-BBD7-DFA0ABB5ACCA}'
Remove-Item -Path 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\{A0953C92-50DC-43bf-BE83-3742FED03C9C}'
#
```

Here is a breakdown of names to CLSID/GUID.

```
Desktop Folder – {B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}
Documents Folder – {A8CDFF1C-4878-43be-B5FD-F8091C1C60D0}
Downloads Folder – {374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}
Music Folder – {1CF1260C-4DD0-4ebb-811F-33C572699FDE}
Pictures Folder – {3ADD1653-EB32-4cb0-BBD7-DFA0ABB5ACCA}
Videos Folder – {A0953C92-50DC-43bf-BE83-3742FED03C9C}
```

Comment: How should OP run them?

Comment: thanks for the explanation and powershell note, still going for the PC tweaker tool in the accepted answer. I feel more confident using a tool for it.

Comment: no biggie, I know HB860 from other forums, his winaero stuff will do the same trick if you don't mind installing an app for it.